# Go Test Coverage - Go Tool Not Recognize err != nil returns

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

I am learning a bit about test coverage in Golang and having some interesting issues.

I have a fair basic code for calling an API and executing the `http.Client.Do(request)`.  After the execution I check for error and return it if its  found.

```
resp, err := Client.Do(request)

if err != nil {
    return response, err
}
```

Also, I have added tests for it. Where I am mocking the `Do` function and returning an error.

```
mocks.DoFunc = func(*http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return nil, errors.New("hello world")
}
```

When I log the `if err != nil` condition, I can see that my code is running and being catch by this simple evaluation.

My problem starts when executing  `go tool cover -html=coverage.out`. The output indicates that this condition is not covered.

SO, why I can check for it when logging and go tool is not detecting it, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Not sure, but worked.

It seems that the Test Order is really important on TestCoverage, creating tests that evaluate from the least to first `if err != nil` did the trick.

My code do a simple fetch an API:

1. Create a  Response object
2. Format the URL + ID
3. Creates a Http.NewREquest
4. Evaluates NewRequest err
5. Executes http.Client.Do(request)
6. Evaluates Do err
7. And So on and on...

...

```
response := &Response{}

url := fmt.Sprintf(pokeapiURLById, pokeId)

request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

resp, err := Client.Do(request)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

...

Tests where created in the following order.

```
func TestFetchById_WhenHttpNewRequestFails(t *testing.T) {...

func TestFetchById_WhenClientDoFails(t *testing.T) {...
```

First, I test the NewRequest err and then Client.Do(req) err. And this way I got 80% of test coverage....

When I changed the order of my test methods:

```
func TestFetchById_WhenClientDoFails(t *testing.T) {...

func TestFetchById_WhenHttpNewRequestFails(t *testing.T) {...
```

I Have 100% of test coverage.
I do not know if its an issue or it supposed to be like that... But, now, it's working good.